# ROS Multiple Packages

Tags: ros

I want to create multiple packages inside a single catkin workspace. I created my package `my_first_pkg` inside `catkin_ws/src`. It worked fine.

Then I tried to add another package in the same path `catkin_ws/src` with the name `my_second_pkg` using `catkin_create_pkg`. Then I run `catkin_make`.

It gives me the following error:

> Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed.

Can you please tell me how to solve this error?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Like, add your CMakeLists.txt and package.xml, maybe you have the same project name or some error like this...it can be anything! Also, don't you have other error messages together with the one you gave us? Usually it gives you the point the error is.

By the way, it's the right procedure to create new packages to add packages in catkin_ws/src through 'catkin_create_pkg'

Comment: Please also add the exact command you use for creating the package.